# PyQt6 Accessing UI Object Attributes

Tags: python, user-interface, qt-designer, pyqt6

I'm trying to create a simple GUI in Python using PyQt6 and Qt Designer.
I've already made the .ui file, and am able to load it properly and have it shown when running the code.

I can't, however, seem able to access any of the objects, i.e buttons and such.
When I print out the children of the AppWindow object I do see all of them listed, but I can't change their attributes via self.button (inside the class init function)- it says 'unresolved attribute reference'.

To my understanding it's supposed to be something trivial, so I'm not quite sure what I had managed to get wrong here.
Would appreciate any help since I'm stumped.

Thank you.

Here's my code-

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt6 import uic


class AppWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi('gui.ui', self)
        self.setWindowTitle('API-SF App')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app_window = AppWindow()
    app_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Do you mean that you have a QPushButton in`gui.ui` named `button`, and when you use `self.button` you get an AttributeError exception? If that's the case, please provide the ui code, otherwise provide a reproducible code and the full traceback.

Comment: The "unresolved attribute reference" is a pycharm-specific warning message. It suggests that you either haven't installed the pyqt6 type-hints, or that pycharm somehow isn't able to use them properly.

Comment: @wimakog1 to expand what already written by ekhumoro, IDEs are not *perfect*, and their code highlighting/management/completion/etc are based on the "static nature" of source code. What you're seeing are *warnings*, because pycharm is not able to compute the attributes `loadUi` will ***dynamically*** create, but they are still *warnings* (automatically generated and also limited by the nature of their implementation): they don't automatically mean that your code is "wrong". The IDE is just unable to foresee what will *actually* happen at runtime. If you're not sure, then just *run* it.

Comment: @musicamante you're right, it was only a pycharm warning, once I did run the code everything went well. Guess I trusted those messages more than I should have. Thank you

Comment: @wimakog1 You're welcome. Just remember that it's important to consider the *meaning* of words (which is always fundamental also in programmings). A "warning" is to *warn* you about something: "hey, pay attention to this, it could be important". It doesn't automatically mean "Everything is lost, we're all gonna die!!¡¡¹". Think about parental warnings: they're important, as their experience can avoid harming ourselves, so they tell us to pay attention as they know the risks we might be facing. But they might also be too protective, as they cannot know our *actual* experience on those matters.